# Submit form with Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I want the download now button to submit the form. 
I have tried

```
getElementById("forms").submit();
$("form").submit();
$("#forms").submit();
```

and still nothing works.

The UI pops up and does everything else it is suppose it but does not submit the form

Java script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog-download ").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 140,
        width: 325,
        modal: true
    });
    $(".opener").click(function(){
        var that = this;
        var checkbox = $(that).next(":checkbox");

        $("#dialog-download").dialog("option", {
            buttons: {
                "Download Now": function(){
                    $(checkbox).prop("checked", !$(checkbox).attr("checked"));
                    $("#dialog-download").dialog("close");
            $("#forms").submit();
                },
                "Download Later ": function(){
                    $(checkbox).prop("checked", !$(checkbox).attr("checked"));
                    $("#dialog-download").dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function(){
                    $("#dialog-download").dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $("#dialog-download").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="dialog-download" title="Download Now?">
    <p><span style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Download the file now or later?</p>
</div>

<form id = "forms" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
<a class="opener" href="#">db1.csv:</a>
<input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="download[]" value="db1.csv" /><br />
<...>
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: Works for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fj2cC/2/

The error has to be in your `action`.

Comment: When I click the Download Now button the alert does not show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the jQuery doc on [`submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

> Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that
>   conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method.
>   Name conflicts can cause confusing failures. For a complete list of
>   rules and to check your markup for these problems, see [DOMLint](http://kangax.github.com/domlint/).

http://jsfiddle.net/Fj2cC/4/

Comment: That was one of the problems the other one was my `if (!isset($_POST['submit']))` i had to change it to `if (!isset($_POST['download']))`